# File not found exception using http url connection?

Tags: java

I have below class.

```
public class Gettype {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {

         URL url = new URL("http://static.ddmcdn.com/gif/recipes/octo-arm-150513 200x200.jpg");
         HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
         connection.setRequestProperty(
                "User-Agent",
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.65 Safari/537.31");

         connection.getInputStream();

    }
```

It throws `FileNotFoundException`. But when I access the same URL (http://static.ddmcdn.com/gif/recipes/octo-arm-150513 200x200.jpg) through browser, it works. Please help me.

Comment: I can not accedd the Image with this URL `http://static.ddmcdn.com/gif/recipes/octo-arm-150513200x200.jpg` Are you sure file is really exist ?

Comment: do you want to store the file local system ?

Comment: There is space before 200x200.jpg. Url is http://static.ddmcdn.com/gif/recipes/octo-arm-150513 200x200.jpg

Comment: When you ask about an exception, always post the exact and complete stack trace in the question. I also get a 404 not found on this URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URL is "http://static.ddmcdn.com/gif/recipes/octo-arm-150513%20200x200.jpg"

replace empty with  `%20`